# weird IF statement error " Conversion from string "FAIL" to type 'Long' is not valid."

Tags: vb.net

I'm basically running through rows in a table. I'm checking each row to see if at least 1 of the columns im interested is = "pass" and that the rest = either "pass" or "N/A".
But im getting an error:

> "An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Conversion from string "FAIL" to type 'Long' is not valid."
The statuses can either be "PASS", "FAIL", OR "N/A" in the DB is you're wondering where the FAIL came from.

Here's the code:

```
Private Function HasAuditPassed(activeLotId As String) As Boolean
    Dim sql = String.Format("SELECT STEPID, CAVITYPAIRASTATUS,CAVITYPAIRBSTATUS,CAVITYPAIRCSTATUS,CAVITYPAIRDSTATUS FROM " & _
                "TB_BL_AMMSSTEPSTATUS WHERE AUDITLOT = '{0}'", activeLotId)

    Dim dynaset = DB.CreateDynaset(sql, DBWrapper.DynasetOptions.ORADYN_READONLY)

    Do Until dynaset.EOF
        Dim cavityPairAStatus = dynaset.GetFieldData(Of String)("CAVITYPAIRASTATUS")
        Dim cavityPairBStatus = dynaset.GetFieldData(Of String)("CAVITYPAIRBSTATUS")
        Dim cavityPairCStatus = dynaset.GetFieldData(Of String)("CAVITYPAIRCSTATUS")
        Dim cavityPairDStatus = dynaset.GetFieldData(Of String)("CAVITYPAIRDSTATUS")

        If (cavityPairAStatus Or cavityPairBStatus Or cavityPairCStatus Or cavityPairDStatus) = "PASS" And
            (cavityPairAStatus And cavityPairBStatus And cavityPairCStatus And cavityPairDStatus) = ("PASS" Or "N/A") Then
            Return True
        End If
    Loop
    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: that is not a valid IF statement.  `If (cavityPairAStatus Or cavityPairBStatus Or cavityPairCStatus Or cavityPairDStatus)` results in a numeric value.  Each needs its own IF `If (cavityPairAStatus = "Pass") Or (cavityPairBStatus = "Pass")`

Comment: Thanks Plutonix , so used to C#, I couldn't see where I was going wrong

Comment: @EricColgan I'm pretty sure that's not valid syntax in C# either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, you can't do if statements that way. You have to write the entire statement out because VB .Net does not handle string comparison that way. So a statement that would be the equivalent and work would be much longer and look like this:

```
If (cavityPairAStatus = "PASS" OrElse cavityPairBStatus = "PASS" OrElse 
    cavityPairCStatus = "PASS" OrElse cavityPairDStatus = "PASS")
    And (cavityPairAStatus = "PASS" OrElse cavityPairAStatus = "N/A" AndAlso
    cavityPairBStatus = "PASS" OrElse cavityPairBStatus = "N/A" AndAlso
    cavityPairCStatus = "PASS" OrElse cavityPairCStatus = "N/A" AndAlso
    cavityPairDStatus = "PASS" OrElse cavityPairDStatus = "N/A") Then
        Return True
End If
```

A few more elegant solutions with creating lists are below, and can be used to help out readability some if you have to write statements like this repeatedly.

Comment: Please do not use `And` and `Or` in visual basic. Those operators are meant for binary operations and do not support short-circut optimization. EDIT: nevermind :D

Comment: Yea i remembered before you did and fixed it! Silly VB isn't in my system right now.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues here. You can't write a `If` stytement in this style and you can't use binary operators (`And` and `Or`) with `String`.

Your `If` statement should be something like this:

```
If (cavityPairAStatus = "PASS" OrElse cavityPairBStatus = "PASS" OrElse  …
```

If you want something a little more elegant you may consider something like this:

```
Dim values = {cavityPairAStatus, cavityPairBStatus, cavityPairCStatus, cavityPairDStatus}
If values.Any(Function(v) v.Equals("PASS")) AndAlso values.All(Function(v) v.Equals("PASS") OrElse v.Equals("N/A")) Then
   …
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The way IF statement you have used is incorrect.
To compare so many conditions you need to write them separately.

Instead of using IF condition here I would suggest you to use a list.
Here's the sample code

```
 Dim cavityPairStatus As New List(Of String)
    cavityPairStatus.Add(dynaset.GetFieldData(Of String)("CAVITYPAIRASTATUS"))
    cavityPairStatus.Add(dynaset.GetFieldData(Of String)("CAVITYPAIRBSTATUS"))
    cavityPairStatus.Add(dynaset.GetFieldData(Of String)("CAVITYPAIRCSTATUS"))
    cavityPairStatus.Add(dynaset.GetFieldData(Of String)("CAVITYPAIRDSTATUS"))
    If cavityPairStatus.Contains("PASS") OrElse cavityPairStatus.Contains("N/A") Then
        Return True
    End If
```